# In angular2-query-builder, I want the field dropdown to be customizable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, angular2-query-builder

While using angular2-query-builder, I can change the type of OPTIONS of a FIELD. I can even add my customized type for OPTIONS. But, for the FIELDS I can't make any such changes. I have a requirement where both the dropdowns should be such that: I should be allowed to type text(alphanumeric). Such that I can search in the dropdown. I have a custom type for this which works similar to DATALIST.

But I can't understand how to embed my change in angular2-query-builder such that I can make changes to FIELD DROPDOWN.

Tried parentFieldTemplate. Changes made for this attribute are not affecting at all.